# Using KochCurve in order to create a fractal

Tags: fractals

I am having trouble creating a Koch curve using the function `KochCurve` in Mathematica. What I want to create is something like this.
[image]

However, what I end up with, using this code:

```
Graphics[KochCurve[2, {0, Pi/2, -Pi/2, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]]
```

is this
[image]

As can be seen, the problem is that the triangles in the curve should be squares. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround you can nest your path and call [`AnglePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath.html):

```
n = 7;
angles = {0, π/2, -π/2, -π/2, π/2};

rots = {0, #} & /@ angles;
init = {1, #} & /@ angles;

iters = NestList[Function[s, Partition[Flatten[{#, s} & /@ rots], 2]], init, n - 1];

ListAnimate[Graphics[Line[AnglePath[#]]] & /@ iters]
```

[image]